# Generated AssembyInfo-file causes Multilingual-App-Toolkit to reset translations

Tags: c#, msbuild, resx, multilingual-app-toolkit

When building our .Net application (Target Framework net461), MSBuild generates the  AssemblyInfo files like:

```
[ApplicationName]_[randomHash]_wpftmp.AssemblyInfo.cs.
```

Additionally we are using MultilingualAppToolkit which references the *.resx file of the project

```
...original="[ApplicationName]/PROPERTIES/RESOURCES.RESX"
```

in the translation file (*.de.xlf). But this path is replaced by

```
...original="[ApplicationName]_[randomHash]_wpftmp/PROPERTIES/RESOURCES.RESX")
```

and therefore all translations (*.de.resx) are resetted, because they are not existing in the new namespace.

Is there any workaround to avoid replacing the "original"-references in the *.xlf file?

Comment: I have run into the same problem. I found this somewhat related issue, but it is still open. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5894